# Use WSDL dynamically in Delphi

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, wsdl

How can I use dynamic WSDL, it's operations and parameters, which is given in program config file?

For example, we have a config file:

```
[Section]
WSDL=http://example.com/SomePub/ws/SomeService?wsdl
Username=myuser
Password=mypass
OperationName=MyOperation
ParameterName=MyParameter
```

I.e. we have to use web-service, which is unknown, but given (by ini-file) only in run-time. So, we cannot use WSDL Import wizard in Delphi.

Can we write in Delphi such a program, which would load these settings from configuration, and then pass data to specified operation in specified parameter on web-service, which specified by given WSDL?

Comment: The nice thing about using it statically is that you get compile time type safety and code completion in the ide. In your code you'll never need to know how data is transferred or even what xml is, because everything is neatly mapped to delphi structures. So do you have specific reasons to use it dynamically?

Comment: Yes, Wouter, I have to.

Comment: If you really need to do this then delphi is not the right tool for the job, it will be easier to achieve your goal in JIT languages like Java or .NET.

Comment: Here is a C# example of what you want: http://codemine.net/post/A-Generic-and-Dynamic-way-to-invoke-remote-WCFWebservice-Web-Method#.UicToz_O5H8

Comment: Take a detour and invoke a Java or .Net application from Delphi ;)

Comment: Guys, Java or .NET are super, but we need native win32 executable...

Comment: You can always construct the SOAP request yourself, foregoing the need to use HTTPRIO. That's exactly what's happening in the C# example in the comments. You can do exactly the same from delphi.

Comment: @whosrdaddy the question is about creation of a valid SOAP request based on a dynamic WSDL, not the SOAP request - I have not yet seen a way to include the Delphi WSDL importer in a Delphi application.

Comment: @mjn, that's what I meant, C# has the option to [dynamically generate the proxy](http://codemine.net/post/Code-for-Dynamically-generating-webproxy-%28CNet%29#.UvuI6_l5PmN). Delphi does not have this, so you'll have to make this yourself...

Answer (score 2):

Using SOAPUI, import the service and perform a sample call. Copy the raw request and the raw response into notepad. Modify the real data with 'tags' and include each raw template as a value in your INI. When you need to make the call, open your INI, grab the raw response template and replace tags with real values. Manually send the SOAP request and parse the response in the same way using the raw template.

Comment: Do you have any sample or something ?

Answer (score 0):

The Delphi WSDL importer and the Free Pascal Web Service Toolkit do not provide a way to build a SOAP request dynamically based on a WSDL.

The Web Service Toolkit (and the WSDL importer) are only source code generators, so the code first needs to be compiled - this requires to include a compiler with your application.